# Android Java: can switch statement avoid inlining when creating a secret string?

Tags: java, android, string, constants, inline

My Android app has to build a secret string at runtime by means of concatenating string constants. I want to avoid inlining of the final string so it cannot be seen from the apk. Say I have the following two functions:

```
private String getConst(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            return getHardCodedConst(1);

        case 2:
            return getHardCodedConst(2);

        case 3:
            return getHardCodedConst(3);

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private String getHardCodedConst(int i) {

    final static String CONST1 = "const1";
    final static String CONST2 = "const2";
    final static String CONST3 = "const3";

    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            return CONST1;

        case 2:
            return CONST2;

        case 3:
            return CONST3;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Are the two following statements inlined? Is one better than the other?

```
myString = getConst(1) + getConst(2) + getConst(3);

myString = getHardCodedConst(1) + getHardCodedConst(2) + getHardCodedConst(3);
```

My code is not so simple and other tricks mask what is really going on but this is an important issue because if the two statements are inlined I do not know how to avoid the string being stolen.

Comment: I do not understand in any way the purpose of what you are doing. Why do you even have a `getHardCodedConst()` method? Why don't you return the constants directly? It makes no difference at all and the only thing you get from doing this is more confusing code.

Comment: why don't you return CONST directly from first method ? what's the need of second one ?

Comment: compiled Java code can in an APK can be found by disassembly  - you will need to use another technique to handle your security (Some sort of client / server interaction after you have authenticated the user with OAuth 2.0?)

Comment: So does the compiler know all can happen in getConst()? How can it decide to inline when some other things can happen? Does it inspect the method to see that only switch statement acts? What if I put a paramter which value is not available at compile time? I think using a parameter set elsewhere is good. Isn't? Or will the compiler bother itself going to discover where I set it?

Comment: @P5music Yes, the compiler knows everything, after all its the compiler who turns your code into byte code. And it doesn't matter where or how you define a variable, if you hardcode the value than it is just plain in your code for everyone to see. All somebody has to do is reverse engineer your APK.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to avoid inlining of the final string so it cannot be seen from
>   the apk.

But you are not hiding the constants just by moving them to another method, what you are doing has only one effect: **It makes you code more confusing for no reason at all**. In fact what you are trying to do is impossible. It doesn't matter what you do, all values in your code can be read from your reverse engineered APK and there is **no way** to prevent that. You can only make it more difficult through [**obfuscation**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

> Are the two following statements inlined? Is one better than the
>   other?

Both are completely equal, it makes no difference at all. If you want to improve this part, then do this:

```
// Declare these as constant fields
private final static String CONST1 = "const1";
private final static String CONST2 = "const2";
private final static String CONST3 = "const3";

...

// Use these constant fields directly to build your String
myString = CONST1 + CONST2 + CONST3;
```

Or even better, do this:

```
// Declare this as constant fields
private final static String CONST1 = "const1";
private final static String CONST2 = "const2";
private final static String CONST3 = "const3";

// Since the resulting String is build from constants it is itself also a constant
// This means we can also declare it as a constant field:
private final static String MY_STRING = CONST1 + CONST2 + CONST3;
```

And if you don't need `CONST1`, `CONST2` or `CONST3` separately then just do this:

```
private final static String MY_STRING = "const1const2const3";
```

All these improvements are just to keep your code clean, maintainable and readable. It makes absolutely no difference aside from that. The program will run in exactly the same way regardless of how or where you define those `Strings`, but doing it like I suggested keeps the  code simple and easy to understand - which by the way should be a good programmers first priority.

<sub>There might be a minuscule performance boost from implementing my suggestions above since there probably is less overhead since you don't need to call any methods. Only accessing fields is very fast.</sub>

---

**FYI:** If you want to store sensitive or important information in a secure location there is only one way: Store it on a server and access it through a web service.

Comment: I only care about inlining, I use other tricks but I have to avoid inlining. Is a parameter set at runtime useful to cheat the compiler in the switch statement?

Comment: Why do you have to avoid it? And what do you expect to happen from avoiding it? I am telling you **it makes no difference**. You are just making your code complicated for **no reason at all**. As I stated in my answer **there is no way to prevent anyone from reading data from your apk**. What you are doing is useless. Imagine it the other way around: When you compile your app and the byte code is generated whatever you do, whether it is inlining stuff or avoiding inlining doesn't matter, if you add a useless method like `getHardCodedConst()` then the compiler will optimise it away anyway.

Comment: I say again: You cannot prevent anyone from stealing information from your apk, and whatever you do to your code has no effect on the ability of someone else to steal the data. If they want it, then they can get it, even if you obfuscate. The only way to keep sensitive data safe is to store them outside of the app on a server and access it through a web service.

Comment: And btw: You don't need a `break;` at the end of a `case` after a `return`. The `return` already breaks the switch. I just can't wrap my  head around this: "Is a parameter set at runtime useful to cheat the compiler in the switch statement?" What do you mean by cheat the compiler? Doesn't make sense...

Comment: And what do you mean by "other tricks"? I can't imagine what you are doing... And what do you think what's going to happen as a result of that? Whatever you do has no effect on the compiled byte code. If you do things like the one in your question then all you get is confusing, hard to understand code for no reason at all. It doesn't change how well or fast the program executes and it doesn't hide any information. It's just making your work harder.

Comment: +1, you just technically can't hide things from clients ( as in client & server ). The best thing you can do is obfuscation and there's indeed tools for that, don't do it in source code.

Comment: I do not know how deeply an Android Java compiler will go bothering itself to inline my code. I think when a function is called with some uncertainty inside, like a parameter that is not known at compile time, inline should not happen. My question just deal with inlining because I know I am not protecting my string from real hackers, I just want to avoid simple reading of a string. Obfuscation is for method names, not strings.

Comment: @P5music you really need to look into obfuscation more, there's [enough tools](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) that obfuscate strings. If you can do it by hand an obfuscator can do it for you.

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean when you say "inline". I can just reiterate again: Whatever you do has no effect on the compiled APK, you can write 1000 useless methods and 500 variables and split your code in as many pieces as you like, but all that does is make your code more complicated, it doesn't change anything about the APK. And I say it again: you cannot prevent anyone from reading the data from your APK, obfuscation just makes it harder.

Comment: And consider this: If somebody wants that String so badly that he is reverse engineering your APK, then he is going to find it, no level of obfuscation is going to stop him. The biggest defence against reverse engineering is the effort it takes and the expertise needed to do it.

Comment: One other thing which you seem to miss: It doesn't matter whether you define `CONST1` as a local variable or a static final constant field, the result is the exact same thing: The `String` is just plainly visible to everyone who reverse engineers your APK, it doesn't matter where or how you define it, it is hardcoded either way and everybody trying to read it from the reverse engineered APK can simply just read it. And if you split it in multiple parts he can just read those parts and check out the code which puts those parts together, so whatever you do, it is completely futile.